# Python letter counting in dict not counting

Tags: python, dictionary

So I was trying to make a word by word counter in python but I kept counting only the letter once. I mean that if the letter was occuring more than once in a sentence the dictionary would not update it is a easy problem but Im just getting started

```
enter code here

import string
"""creating a dict made of letters and values as 0"""
counter=dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase,0)
test=counter

first=str(input("enter a sentence:"))
def fuc():
   char=counter.keys()
   for i in char:
        if i in first and char:
            test[i] = first.count(i)

fuc()
print(test)
```

Comment: `str(input())` is redundant `input()` returns a `str`.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add what specific problem you encountered and what your question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you get is indeed what one would expect from your code - for each character in `counter.keys()` (IOW for each character in `string.ascii_lowercase`), if the character is in the sentence, you are increasing the counter by one. Since each character in `counter.keys()` is garanteed to appear only once, its counter can only be incremented one at best.

As a side note, there are a few things in your code that are either useless or not doing what you might expect:

This:

```
test = counter
```

doesn't do a copy of `counter`, it just make both names pointing to the same object. You probably want to [read this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for a more in-depth (but very clear) explanation.

If you want a copy of an object, you have to ask for it explicitely. In your case, a shallow copy is enough since your dict's values are immutable, so you can just use `dict.copy()`:

```
test = counter.copy()
```

If your values were mutable - for example if you had a dict of lists and want the lists themselves to be copied too -, you'd have to use `copy.deepcopy()` instead:

```
>>> d = {"a": []}
>>> dd = d.copy()
>>> # d and dd are different objects
>>> d is dd
False
>>> # but d["a"] and dd["a"] are still the same object
>>> d["a"] is dd["a"]
True
>>> # now with a deep copy:
>>> import copy
>>> ddd = copy.deepcopy(d)
>>> # this time the values have been copied too
>>> d["a"] is ddd["a"]
False
```

Here:

```
first=str(input("enter a sentence:"))
```

If you're using Python3, `input()` is garanteed to return a string, so no need to make it a string again.

If you're using Python 2.x, well, you should really move to Python3 - Python 2 is officially dead now. But if you're not, you want to use `raw_input()` instead.

And here:

```
if i in first and char:
```

I'm not sure what you expect the `and char` part to do, but in this case it's only eating CPU cycles for nothing. the expression `i in first and char` is parsed as `(i in first) and (char)` - so first the left part `(i in first)` is evaluated, yielding a boolean. Then the second part  `(char)` is evaluated too. Since it's a non-empty container (if it was empty the loop's body would not exexute at all), it always have a true value in a boolean context. IOW, you could rewrite this as

```
if i in first and True:
```

which makes the expression's values depending only on the first part, so it's equivalent to

```
if i in first:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `count()` instead:

```py
import string
test = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase,0)
first = input("enter a sentence:")

def func():
    for i in set(first):
        test[i] = first.count(i)

func()
print(test)
```